# Simulating behavior of different versions of Mac OS X in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, ocunit

In efforts to bullet-proof a few aspects of a Mac application I maintain, I'm introducing a new suite of unit tests surrounding the saving/loading components of the code.

The tests have been written, and pass under 10.7 Lion using the proper NSFileCoordinator method calls.

*But:* There are portions of the code that will branch if running under 10.6 Snow Leopard (and some classes are not available), and will branch even further if running under 10.5 Leopard.

My current "testing" strategy is to triple-boot the three operating systems. I build and test in 10.7, then I reboot and build and test in 10.6, then I reboot and build and test in 10.5.

As you can imagine, this gets frustrating and is a huge diversion from *getting stuff done.*

**My Question:** Are there any commercial/known methods for testing Objective-C code under different versions of Mac OS X (and thus different behaviors) without actually requiring that version of Mac OS X to be the version running? *(Preferably without using a VM)*

I have trouble picturing Apple releasing a new update for iPhoto and testing it on 15 different Macs running 10.6.0, 10.6.1, 10.6.2... etc.

Comment: Apple has the least problem testing things across versions as they have a division of testers.

Comment: I'm sure they have plenty of testers, but I'm sure that the thought of not having to do it *this way* must have crossed their minds at some point.

Comment: I think you can change the base sdk for that, it adds warning about calls and classes that don't exist, but I think it permits it to be run if its on a new OS.

Comment: But building and running an application in Xcode using the 10.6 base SDK wouldn't cause it to run as if it were running on an actual 10.6 machine, right? If I perform method calls that are only available in 10.7 Lion, or do any **[... respondsToSelector:...]** calls, their return values will reflect the state of the current running OS, not the SDK of the OS the application was built against.

Comment: as I said, all it does is add warnings.